# GCM notification not displayed

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to use feature, when android automatically displays notifications on receiving push messages as described [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/downstream#notifications_and_data_messages) 
It seems notification not only not diplayed, but `onMessageReceived` not fired at all when I add `notification` field to my JSON payload. Without this field all goes fine.
Here my json payload:

```
{
 "to":"APA91bGIe59H1V5SsQkKvDOTgCTEaZWwgCJrdQ...",
 "message_id":"",
 "notification":{
                 "body":"Notification test",
                 "title":"Notification header",
                 "icon":"noti.png"
                },
 "data":{
         "test_message":"GCM test message!"
        }
}
```

So, why can this happen? Or there are no auto notifications? (What for is `notification` field, if so... I can use `data` field if I must generate notifications by myself)

**Edit:** 
Finally got it to work. The icon field should be like `"icon":"@drawable/noti"`
Google documentation errors are really annoying.

Comment: You need to put the notification inside the data object.

Comment: @Prokash Why if documentation says use separate field? Anyway, not working. Message is delivered as expected, but no notification.

Comment: @StenSoft yes and yes, I am using latest google example https://github.com/google/gcm

Comment: "icon": "noti" should also work as described in the documentation: "Indicates notification icon. On Android: sets value to myicon for drawable resource myicon.png."

Comment: This problem would be diagnosed before if you post the messages displayed in your LogCat....

Comment: @Elenasys you right, but it acts strangely sometimes if I'm not restarting adb manually. Should reinstall Android Studio maybe

Answer (score 0):

In my case the notification was not displayed, because I haven't set the notification item while building the notification.
This builder worked:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
                .setContentTitle("GCM Message")
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```